# how can i plot a graph with timedelta using matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, timedelta

i am trying to plot a graph with dattime X timedelta

http://pastebin.com/QsnXdU0j

```
def graph_entre_mamadas(tempo_entre_mamadas):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib
    eixo_x = [i[0] for i in tempo_entre_mamadas]
    eixo_y = [i[1] for i in tempo_entre_mamadas]
    #print eixo_x
    #print eixo_y

    plt.plot(eixo_x, eixo_y, 'ro')
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.show()
```

my variable eixo_x is a list of datetime.datetime and eixo_y variable is a list of datetime.timedelta.

when i execute this method i get this error:

```
  graph_entre_mamadas(tempo_entre_mamadas_v)
  File "consome_mama.py", line 111, in graph_entre_mamadas
    plt.plot(eixo_x, eixo_y, 'ro')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2832, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3997, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1507, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1516, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 677, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 410, in recache
    y = np.asarray(yconv, np.float_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 320, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number



eixo_x : [datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 9, 21, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 10, 50, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 13, 26, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 15, 36, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 16, 36, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 23, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 20, 40, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 21, 20, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 22, 11, 28), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 28, 2, 42, 28)]
eixo_y : [datetime.timedelta(0, 9000), datetime.timedelta(0, 4440), datetime.timedelta(0, 8100), datetime.timedelta(0, 7140), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800), datetime.timedelta(0, 1920), datetime.timedelta(0, 10920), datetime.timedelta(0, 1320), datetime.timedelta(0, 1920), datetime.timedelta(0, 13740)]
```

how can i do this?

Comment: You aren't calling your function. Also, it's unusual to be importing inside a function.

Comment: in my script i call the function and i get this error:

Comment: What do eixo_x and eixo_y look like? Do they end up being lists of floats?

Comment: eixo_x is a list of datetime.datetime and eixo_y variable is a list of datetime.timedelta

Comment: To me, it looks like you're having a problem with tempo_entre_mamadas_v not containing numbers where you think it does.

Comment: i put the values at the description

Comment: convert the time delta to seconds.  I don't think this is supported.

Answer (score 0):

**Matplotlib do not provide a simple method to convert timedelta**.

But, you can convert a date in matplotlib float representation easily using `matplotlib.dates.date2num`.

So, a working solution is to create a date using the starting time plus the delta, then convert them with `date2num`, and finally make a difference between the two dates when they are converted.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib
import datetime

x0 = datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 9, 21, 28)
duration = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
converted_starting_time = matplotlib.dates.date2num(x0)
converted_finish_time = matplotlib.dates.date2num(x0 + duration)
converted_delta = converted_finish_time - converted_starting_time
```